# MySQL Ambiguous Option issue

Tags: 12.04, mysql

MySQL is starting correctly as a service, and my WP instance / phpMyAdmin connects to it successfully.  However, I've managed to screw something up such that when I try to log in from the prompt, mysql spits out an error about an Ambiguous Option issue, even when I provide no options.

```
gregory@myserver:~$ mysql 
mysql: ambiguous option '--v' (vertical, version)
```

I do not think I have an alias set, and I tried the following (note the backslash):

```
gregory@server:~$ \mysql
mysql: ambiguous option '--v' (vertical, version)
```

Any ideas?  I would prefer solving this rather than trying to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likley is a corrupted `/etc/my.cnf` file.

Check it if you have any formatting errors there.

Comment: I could kiss you.  I took a look already once, but with your prodding, and looked more carefully and I must have typed a "v" just before saving some edits last time, and I never noticed.  Thanks...  I'm surprised the mysql service was still able to run with an invalid cnf file.  That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Glad i could help :)